# How can I add these characters to every line that includes a specific letter in a specific column? (notepad++)

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a huge list of entries I need to get region codes added for.  The region is dictated/determined by the letter present in the 4th column.

Here are some examples

```
WKNEAY            USA              Title                         Shovel Knight
WKNPAY            PAL              Title                         Shovel Knight
AUMED2            USA              Title                         Minecraft: Super Mario Edition                                                                                                                                                                               
AA2E                               eShop                         Archery
AA3E                               eShop                         The Deer God
AA9E                               eShop                         Art Academy: SketchPad
AA9J                               eShop                         絵心教室 スケッチ
AA9P                               eShop                         Art Academy: SketchPad
AAHJ                               eShop                         タイニーシーフ
AAVE                               eShop                         amiibo tap: Nintendo's Greatest Bits
```

The first 3 I have done by hand.  As shown, the 4th character being an "E" indicates its  USA.  Some ID's are 4 characters long, some 6.  Its always going to be the 4th letter I want to use.

I'm hoping some regex exists that will simply seek out if `E` is in the `4th column`, add `USA` to the end (ideally preceded by a space) or something to that effect.  I'm unconcerned with it shifting the rest of the stuff forward as I can always mass-move it back to where it needs to be.  I just cant add region codes to thousands of randomly strewn entries by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^...E\S*\h\K\h{3}`
- Replace with: `USA`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  ...           # 3 characters
  E             # letter E
  \S*           # 0 or more non spaces
  \h            # 1 horizontal space
  \K            # forget all we have seen until this position
  \h{3}         # 3 horizontal spaces
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: thank you very much!  Perfect answer :)

Comment: @klepp0906: You're welcome, glad it helps.